# Expand DataTable to fill height in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, fill

I have a problem with flutter.
I need to fill a DataTable in the height of screen.

I tried to add the dataTable inside a Flex widget, but I don't get changes.

When I set the heigh of the Container, that's work let me a white space at the button of the screen

Thank you! and i'm sorry for mi poor english

This my code:

```
products.addAll(Product.getExampleList());

var table =

Container(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child:SizedBox(
            child:
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                DataTable(
                    columns: <DataColumn>[
                      DataColumn(
                          label: Text("Código")
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text("Precio"),
                        numeric: true,
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                          label: Text("Grupo")
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                          label: Text("Descripción")
                      ),
                    ],
                    rows:
                    products.map<DataRow>((Product element) {
                      return DataRow(
                        key: Key(element.idProduct.toString()),
                        cells: <DataCell>[
                          DataCell(Text(element.code)),
                          DataCell(Text("\$ " + element.price.toStringAsFixed(2))),
                          DataCell(Text(element.group)),
                          DataCell(Text(element.description))
                        ],
                      );
                    }).toList()
                ),
              ],
            )
        ),
      ),
);


return  Container(
    color: Colors.white24,
    child:
      Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Row(

            children: <Widget>[

              Text("Código: "),
              Flexible(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: tController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Ingrese Código"
                  ) ,
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: onPressedSearch,
                child: Text("Buscar"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Flex(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            table
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
);
```

Comment: Have you used Wrap content?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the `dataRowHeight` and `headingRowHeight` properties of the `DataTable` to make its height equal to screen height.

```dart
your_number_of_rows = 4;
rowHeight = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 56) / your_number_of_rows;

DataTable(dataRowHeight: rowHeight, headingRowHeight: 56.0, columns: ...)
```

Comment: Sorry, but why -56?

Comment: I don't remember. Maybe it is the default value. You can change it to any value. It is used two times in the code snippet above. @hunterlan

Answer (score 2):

In accord with the official documentation, the parameter `dataRowHeight` is deprecated, as shown below.

> `dataRowHeight` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Migrate to use
> dataRowMinHeight and dataRowMaxHeight instead. This feature was
> deprecated after v3.7.0-5.0.pre.

So you should use

```
DataTable(          
         dataRowMinHeight: 25.0,
         dataRowMaxHeight: 28.0,
...
```

Comment: Hello, Neemias!  I saw that you are a new contributor. Welcome to the community. 

Writing here in portuguese is not allowed and could result in answer exclusion or downvotes. Don't worry, i just translated your post and everything is ok now. You will soon get a hold in the community standards. You should write posts here only in english. We have another community (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) if you want to contribute in portuguese. 

Bem vindo!

Comment: hi, thank you for me alert in relation a this. but i hope e help in english same, for up to train  my write in english, because I suck.

Comment: It's just practice. If you want to contribute to the english forum, you can always write a draft in portuguese and then translate it to english, with the help of some translation tool.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the **dataRowMaxHeight: double.infinity** will help you..

```
          DataTable(
          sortAscending: true,
          columnSpacing: 2.0,
          dataRowMaxHeight: double.infinity,       // Code to be changed.
          dataRowMinHeight: 60,                    // Set the min required height.
          dividerThickness: 1,
          columns: <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(
                label: Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                child: Text(
                  'Account Type',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center
                ),
              ),
            ))]),
```